# How remove large space between the sentences in text file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working with Unicode file after processing it. I am getting very large spacing between sentences for example

```
 തൃശൂരില്‍ ഹര്‍ത്താല്‍ പൂര്‍ണം 



 തൃശൂവില്‍ ഇടതുമുന്നണി ഹര്‍ത്താലില്‍ ജനജീവിതം പൂര്‍ണമായും സ്‌... 





 ഡി.വൈ.എഫ്‌.ഐ. ഉപരോധം; കലക്‌ടറേറ്റ്‌ സ്‌തംഭിച്ചു 



 തൃശൂര്‍: നിയമനനിരോധനം, അഴിമതി, വിലക്കയറ്റം എന്നീ വിഷയങ്ങള്‍ മുന്‍... 





 ബൈക്ക്‌ പോസ്‌റ്റിലിടിച്ച്‌ പതിന്നേഴുകാരന്‍ മരിച്ചു
```

How to remove these large spaces ?

I have tried this

```
" ".join(raw.split())
```

It is not working at all. Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is `raw`? A file object?

Comment: @alKid Yeah, file object

Comment: why down vote? always

Comment: By the way, do you want to edit the file or just get the processed data?

Comment: check my answer. It might have what you need.

Comment: @ aIKid I am trying it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to write the results another file, or rewrite it to your file. Most operating systems doesn't allow us to edit *directly* into a file, especially appending. For simple cases like this, rewriting is much simpler:

```
with open('f.txt') as raw:
    data = ''.join(raw.read().split()) #If you want to remove newlines only, use split('\n')

with open('f.txt', 'w') as raw:
    raw.write(data)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, It is working fine. but we have to use split('\n')

Answer (score 0):

Assuming raw is your raw data, you need to split the raw data using `str.splitlines`, filter all the empty lines, and rejoin them using newline

```
print '\n'.join(line for line in raw.splitlines() if line.strip())
```

If you are open to use regex, you may also try

```
import re
print re.sub("\n+","\n", raw)
```

If instead `raw` is a file object, group all consecutive spaces as one

```
from itertools import groupby

with open("<some-file>") as raw:
    data = ''.join(k for k, _ in groupby(raw))
```

Comment: @karu: Which part you are failing to understand?

Comment: Ok got it  second one is fine

Answer (score 0):

assuming the lines are empty (only a newline) using python:

```
import re
import sys

f = sys.argv[1]

for line in open(f, 'r'):
    if not re.search('^$', line):
        print line
```

or if you prefer:

```
egrep -v "^$" <filename>
```